# Taylor's formula in several variables.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Below is a note written by Folland about Taylor's formula in several variables.
https://www.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor2.pdf

He asserts in page 2 that $g(t)^{(j)} = (h \dot \triangledown f)^{j}(f(a+th))\ $  where $g(t) = f(a + th)$ and $(h \dot \triangledown f) = h_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \dotsb + h_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$.

I can see that $g(t)' = h_1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \dotsb + h_n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$ because it is simply the directional derivative of $f$ at direction $h$. But why $\frac{d\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}}{dt} = (h \dot \triangledown f)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first derivative:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} f(a+th) = \left(\sum_i h_i \partial_i\right) f(a+th)$$
Then
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left(\partial_k f(a+th)\right)=\left(\sum_i h_i \partial_i\right) \partial_k f (a+th) $$ so as $h$ is constant:
$$ g''(t) = \left(\sum_i h_i \partial_i\right) \left(\sum_k h_k \partial_k\right)f(a+th)=  \left(\sum_i h_i \partial_i\right)^2f(a+th)$$
and you may proceed by induction.

Comment: Can you explain why $ \frac{d}{dt} \left(\partial_k f(a+th)\right)=\left(\sum_i h_i \partial_i\right) \partial_k f (a+th)$. That is where it confuses me.

Comment: You may view it as $\frac{d}{dt} (\partial_k f) (a+th)$ where $\partial_k f$ is simply a function like any other which is a function of $a+th$ and then again differentiable wrt $t$ as in the first formula (at least when assuming $f\in C^2$), if you feel comfortable with the first formula?

Comment: Yes, I tried to think like this before, but I just cannot persuade myself using this argument. If I take an arbitrary function how can I judge whether it is a function of a+th or not?

Comment: There is a non-trivial issue about interchanging limits but apart from that take a function of two variables $f(a_1+th_1,a_2+th_2)$ then for fixed $t$ and $h$ you may write: $\partial_1 f(a+th) = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a_1+th_1+s,a_2+th_2)-f(a_1+th_1,a_2+th_2)}{s}$ which simply becomes the function $\partial_1 f$ evaluated at the point $a+th$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much!